# transfer value from multiple check box selection to text field

Tags: jquery

I have a accordion element holds multiple check box and i hope the value that anyone selected those check boxes can be transferred into another textfield, if the user uncheck the box, then the textfield should reflect the change. please help with the jQuery. the code is below. Thanks.

```
            <ul>
                <li><input type="checkbox" id="chk1"> check 1</li>
                <li><input type="checkbox" id="chk2"> check 2</li>
                <li><input type="checkbox" id="chk3"> check 3</li>
                <li><input type="checkbox" id="chk4"> check 4</li>
                <li><input type="checkbox" id="chk5"> check 5</li>
            </ul>
            <input name="value-holder" type="text" id="value-holder" />

            <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#SliderCloseButton").click(function(){
                    $('#value-holder').prepend( $('#chk1') );
                    $('#value-holder').prepend( $('#chk2') );
                    $('#value-holder').prepend( $('#chk3') );
                    $('#value-holder').prepend( $('#chk4') );
                    $('#value-holder').prepend( $('#chk5') );
                });
            });
            </script>
```

Comment: well you need some Javascript for this task and you should at least attempt it before asking for help.

Comment: What do you mean by "same format"?

Comment: thanks for the reply, i just changed the question and added the code. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this in your script.

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
    var checkedVals = $("input:checkbox:checked").map(function() {
        return this.value;
    }).get();

    $("#textbox").val(checkedVals.join(","));
});
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/uH4us/4/)